# primary key should always be unsigned?

Tags: mysql, database

since a primary key (identifier) wont be under 0, i guess it should always be unsigned?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

TL/DR: **Yes, but it almost doesn't matter.**

Auto-increment always increases, so it will never use negative values. You might as well make it unsigned, and you get twice the range of values.

On the other hand, if your table uses 2<sup>31</sup> values, it will probably also use 2<sup>32</sup> values in a short time, so having twice the range of values isn't a big difference. You will have to upgrade to BIGINT anyway.

---

MySQL supports an optional `SERIAL` data type (presumably for compatibility with PostgreSQL, since `SERIAL` is not standard ANSI SQL).  This data type is just shorthand that creates a `BIGINT UNSIGNED`.

Go ahead try it:

```
CREATE TABLE test.foo (foo_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY);

SHOW CREATE TABLE test.foo;

CREATE TABLE `test`.`foo` (
  `foo_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`foo_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `foo_id` (`foo_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

You get the same number of distinct values whether you declare an integer signed or unsigned: 2<sup>32</sup> for an `INT` and 2<sup>64</sup> for a `BIGINT`.  If the number is unsigned, you get values from 0 to that max value minus one.  If the number is signed, you get values from `-max/2` to `max/2-1`.  Either way, you get the same absolute number of distinct values.

But since `AUTO_INCREMENT` starts at zero by default and increments in the positive direction, it's more convenient to utilize the positive values than the negative values.

But it hardly matters that you get 2X as many positive values.  Any table that would exceed the maximum signed integer value 2<sup>31</sup>-1 is likely to continue to grow, so you should just use a `BIGINT` for these tables.

You're really, really, *really* unlikely to allocate more than 2<sup>63</sup>-1 primary key values, even if you delete all your rows and re-load them many times a day.

Comment: Just for maximum clarity: SERIAL is specifically an alias for "BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE", as of MySQL 4.1+.

Comment: I didnt' get an answer. So should primary key always be signed  or unsigned?

Comment: @Tebe, on one hand, yes, auto-increment always increases, so it will never use negative values. You might as well make it unsigned, and you get twice the range of values. But on the other hand, if you would use 2^31 values, you will probably also use 2^32 values in a few months, so you will have to upgrade to BIGINT anyway.

Comment: I'd take care: If you upgrade to unsigned, you likely will need to switch to a larger Number type in your programming language. E.g. Long instead of Integer, or something like BigInteger instead of Long. This can have quite an impact on the software part (memory consumption, performance, adjustment effort) and imho not worth the doubling of values.

Answer (score 8):

Why exactly are you presuming that a primary key won't be under 0? That is not a given. I think you are confusing it with an identity column.

In any case it should make no appreciable difference either way, map the data type to the type of data you expect in the column regardless of whether it is a primary key or not.

Comment: but if i have an INT unsigned, doesnt that mean i will have the double amount of positive numbers i can use?

Comment: You expecting to need more than  2,147,483,647 records in your tables, often? In the spirit of the late Doug Adams I'll adjust my answer to state that signed integers for an identity column are "mostly harmless"

Comment: MySQL treats negative integers in a primary key as greater than 0 for the purposes of creating the next one.

Comment: staticsan - are you sure about this? I created a test table with mixed positive and negative PK values, and I don't see any such consideration of the negative values.

Answer (score 4):

> since a primary key (identifier) wont be under 0

I assume from that statement that your primary key also auto-increments.

If it does, then is is very sensible to ensure your column is unsigned, for the reason described in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

> An AUTO_INCREMENT column works properly only if it contains only positive values. Inserting a negative number is regarded as inserting a very large positive number. This is done to avoid precision problems when numbers “wrap” over from positive to negative and also to ensure that you do not accidentally get an AUTO_INCREMENT column that contains 0.

If you are inserting negative numbers into an auto-incrementing column, then you are probably solving a problem the wrong way.

Answer (score 3):

NO - a primary key wont always be unsigned for example:

```
 create table user_status
 (
  status_id tinyint not null primary key,
  name varchar(64) not null,
  msg varchar(255) default null
 )engine=innodb;

 insert into user_status values 
    (-99,'banned', 'Account banned'), 
    (-2,'closed', 'Account closed'),
    (-1,'unverified', 'Account not verified'),
    (0,'suspended','Account suspended'),
    (1,'active', null);
```

if this was an orders table however i'd use order_id int unsigned

Comment: Your example is likely (I've seen it before). But I guess the asker is more interested in an broad view explanation of the motivations for doing so.

Comment: You're overloading the use of a primary key. Status should be separate column. This is not a good design.

Comment: @PhilT -  we all have to write business/application logic which utilises the relational data we have stored in our wonderfully normalised schemas. However, in my experience having signed integer primary keys, especially on status or type tables can help simplify business logic considerably. It may not be good design in your book but in mine it works great.

Comment: I appreciate the world is not perfect but using a bad example to prove your case is propagating bad design. What happens to the associated records when you ban an account? You've lost the original ID. How do you unsuspend an account? Do you give it a new primary key?  Perhaps saying that designs such as these exist and so it's possible that primary keys would be signed but I maintain this is such a bad idea.

Comment: @PhilT - You are merely changing the user_status_id (foreign key) in the user table to -99. Nothing else changes except now your business logic is preventing that account from logging into the system - the integrity of the related relational data e.g. orders, threads, accounts, etc is maintained. I think you need me to add a user table to my example :)

Comment: Sorry I skipped over the `_status` part of the `user_status` name and just read `user`.

Comment: Still, I'd say this was overnormalization. Just use a status string in the user table which tells you the status without having to refer to this table. Strings can be indexed without loss of performance. The message should be contained in your application (unless of course your whole application is written in the db then I guess it works). I guess your reasoning is that anything other than 1 is an inactive account.

Comment: I'd remove the downvote but it's locked unless you edit the answer.